# WebSharper Minimum Browser Requirements

Tags: f#, websharper, minimum-requirements

So . . . I have been playing around with WebSharper recently and wanted to check something at work.  So, I loaded up IE7, our browser, to go to the WebSharper samples page - http://www.websharper.com/SamplesPage.  However, I got a rude surprise when I saw that none of the pages or samples would load.

So, my question is this - what are the minimum client requirements for using a WebSharper-created website?  I am using the HTML/JS client-side only configuration in my project, so maybe the requirements are lower for that (I doubt that)?

The manual contains no helpful information that I could find.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

z.

Comment: Thanks noting this, it is a bug I think. It should work for IE7. I will be checking this.

Answer (score 1):

I remember having problem with RPC calls in IE8 and IE9 resolved my problems. As Toyvo pointed out, I'm sure the team at IntelliFactory intends to be fairly backward compatible so I recommend you open a bugzilla.

I suppose you are on IE7 because of company policy? I mean, IE9 is a pretty bad browser - IE7 is just begging for trouble.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response.  Yes, IE7 is due to company policy.  However, the reason I mention it is just to give an example.  If I write a web app open to the public, I want it to work on the largest group of browsers possible.  I'm writing my own app right now as a test.  We'll see how it goes.